# How to customize a standard encryption algorithm?

Tags: encryption, aes

I want to modify and customize AES encryption algorithm and develop a variant of it. What factors should I consider so that it does not become weaker? What skill sets would be required to undertake this task? How complicated can it get?

Comment: What do you mean by "customize"? Do you really want to modify the entrails of the algorithm, or do you just need a parameterized block cipher built on top of AES (with provably equal strength) to differentiate it from other uses of AES, akin to Skein's personalization string?

Comment: I want to modify the algorithm itself.

Comment: I think the answer to your questions (in particular the last question) depends a lot on what kind of customizations you want to do. Maybe you could be more specific?

Comment: @Guut Boy: Frankly, I haven't started thinking about it yet. I got this problem statement and was wondering how to go about it. P.S: It is not a homework.

Comment: First, you need to clarify why do you need to modify AES. E.g.: Do you want it to be faster? Different block sizes? More suitable for some specific hardware? etc.

Comment: Note the PDF link is no longer relevant: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.crypt/G59kkTswyjk

Comment: @cygnusv: I do not want to use the standard AES because it is known to everyone. The variant should be as strong yet sufficiently different from the original.

Comment: @Richie Frame: I checked the link. It would be very helpful if you can summarize your observations.

Comment: summary: methods to improve the diffusion of AES variants that still allow use of AES_NI instructions. new pdf: http://wikisend.com/download/495024

Comment: "I do not want to use the standard AES because it is known to everyone." Actually, that is *why* you should use standard AES. [Security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) is one of the major pitfalls in IT security, because people don't take  [Kerckhoffs's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle) seriously.

Comment: @Jay If meerly not knowing the cipher adds any appreciable security to a system then that means the cipher is broken to begin with in a way no tweak will fix. As in, the difference in difficultly breaking AES between knowing the algorithm and not knowing it at all is completely insignificant and lost in the noise. By modifying it to keep it secret, you add no meaningful security at best but have a fairly good chance of significantly reducing the security. Unintuitive, but true.

Comment: Kerckhoffs said neither "publish everything" nor "keep everything secret"; rather, he said that the system should still be secure even if the enemy has a copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments on the question are very good. That said, I'll try to address the question(s).

> What factors should I consider so that it does not become weaker?

This is a very important concern that I am glad you have. One of the big strengths that standard ciphers have is that lots of really smart people have looked at them and have not been able to break them. See [Schneier's Law](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html) -- "Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break."

So normally the answer to this question would be to publish the details of the modification so that other cryptographers can analyze them and determine whether or not security has been weakened due to your modifications. Based on your comments, however, it sounds like that might violate other design constraints (BTW, I agree with the other commenters that keeping your algorithm secret is a poor choice). So, instead, I'd recommend hiring a group of experts to review the design and point out any fatal flaws. Actually, what I'd really recommend is that you use standard ciphers and just keep the key secret.

> What skill sets would be required to undertake this task?

Years of experience breaking ciphers. There are lots of ways to gain this expertise, but no shortcuts. It will take years of experience. That said, what modifications you make will have a great impact on what experience you need. For example, could the changes possibly create side-channel attacks? If so, you need that experience. The less you change the better and the easier it will be to do the analysis, but at the same time, the less you change, the more I have to wonder why you are changing anything at all. Make sense?

> How complicated can it get?

Depends on what you do. It could get very, very complicated. To the point that you are really not changing things and really creating a new cipher.

For a recent example of an "updated" cipher, I suggest you look at the [Spritz](http://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/pubs/RS14.pdf) cipher. It is an "update" to RC4. Maintains similar structure to the RC4 cipher but has very significant modifications. Also, take a look at [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/985) which claims statistical weaknesses in Spritz. See, even seasoned pros can potentially get things wrong when updating/modifying a standard cipher. This also is a good example of why publishing your cipher is a good thing.